# What's the difference between "purge" and "remove --purge"?

Tags: command-line

What is the difference between `sudo apt-get purge` and `sudo apt get remove --purge`?

There must be a difference or both of them shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whether they should or shouldn't both exist is perhaps a debating point.

However - they are absolutely identical.

From the man page of `apt-get`

```
--purge
           Use purge instead of remove for anything that would be removed. An
           asterisk ("*") will be displayed next to packages which are
           scheduled to be purged.  remove --purge is equivalent to the purge
           command. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Purge.
```

They key part is *--purge is equivalent to the purge command*

As to why - I would surmise this is historical -

`apt-get --purge remove` came before `apt-get purge`

Looking at the [old apt](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html#s-remove) documentation it make reference to the older version of the command.  The [newer documentation](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_purging_removed_packages_for_good) gives the `aptitude` & `apt-get purge` example.

For the sake of consistency - its a good idea to not remove old interfaces - if you have an old script - it will still work today because the interface commands still exist.

Mind you that doesnt stop Gnome from deprecating api's - but that's another story...

Comment: If I might add, the `--purge` switch comes in handy when you use the `autoremove` command. There is no other way that I know to make `apt-get` delete configuration files of packages that are being automatically removed.

Comment: There is a nice thing about having both in that you can combine --purge with `apt-get autoremove`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one as far as I know, they do the same thing exactly, remove packages and try to remove any configuration files created by those packages.

Basically `apt-get purge` was implemented after `apt-get remove --purge` but the old option styled purge still remained.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, as it says in the official man page: `remove --purge is equivalent to the purge command.` See `man apt` and the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html). I think the usage developed and both commands remained; as happens in other programs, usage changes and one form (i.e. `sudo apt-get purge`) becomes preferred over the other. However, I am still looking for a reference for this and researching the history of the usage, although there are useful chapters on package management in the [Debian Handbook](http://debian-handbook.info/download/stable/debian-handbook.pdf) and articles on apt-get at [Raphael Hertzog's blog](http://raphaelhertzog.com/).

Using the example of removing vlc (albeit with the `-s` simulate flag), we can see that the commands have identical results; all the other files used by vlc need to be removed with `sudo apt-get autoremove` in both cases.

1)  `sudo apt-get remove --purge`

```
sudo apt-get -s remove --purge vlc
[sudo] password for mike: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdc1394-22 libxcb-keysyms1 libzvbi0 libxcb-xv0 libtar0 libass4 libdvbpsi7
  libvlc5 vlc-nox libupnp3 libzvbi-common libxcb-randr0 libxcb-composite0
  libiso9660-8 libkate1 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vlc-data
  libdirac-encoder0 libvlccore5 libvcdinfo0 libebml3 libmatroska5
  libsdl-image1.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  vlc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg vlc [2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1]
```

2) `sudo apt-get purge`

```
sudo apt-get -s purge vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libdc1394-22 libxcb-keysyms1 libzvbi0 libxcb-xv0 libtar0 libass4 libdvbpsi7
  libvlc5 vlc-nox libupnp3 libzvbi-common libxcb-randr0 libxcb-composite0
  libiso9660-8 libkate1 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse vlc-data
  libdirac-encoder0 libvlccore5 libvcdinfo0 libebml3 libmatroska5
  libsdl-image1.2
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  vlc*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Purg vlc [2.0.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As previous answers have stated, the two are indeed equivalent.

One valid reason does come to mind for the continued existence of both forms, however:

- `apt-get purge` is a useful, later-added shorthand for the complete removal of specific packages
- The `--purge` flag allows modification of other apt-get calls to purge configuration files as well, as in `apt-get autoremove --purge`

As a regular experimenter with new software, I myself have had considerably less old configuration files floating around since learning how to modify autoremove calls!

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this with `apt` instead of `apt-get` to remove old kernels. The `remove` command deleted them, but they were still showing as packages of size 0B. The `--purge remove` option actually made them stop showing up.

```
:~$ uname -r
5.19.0-41-generic
:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1
linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic
linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic
:~$ sudo apt remove linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 12.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 202847 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-40-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1
linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic
linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic
:~$ sudo apt --purge  remove linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.19.0-40-generic linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-40 linux-modules-5.19.0-40-generic linux-modules-extra-5.19.0-40-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic* linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 202843 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.19.0-40-generic (5.19.0-40.41~22.04.1) ...
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/5.19.0-40-generic': Directory not empty
Purging configuration files for linux-image-5.19.0-38-generic (5.19.0-38.39~22.04.1) ...
:~$ dpkg --get-selections | grep "linux-image-[[:digit:]].*" | tr "\t" ";" | cut -d ";" -f1
linux-image-5.19.0-41-generic
```